# how to integration zoom Chart with angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, zoomcharts

is this possible to integrate Zoom chart with angular 2need basic idea is anyone done this before , didn't find any thread related to this on Internet that's why i asked here, any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

## 1. [Description based on `angular-seed` application](https://forum.zoomcharts.com/t/zoomcharts-with-angularjs/111/6?u=karlis)

> For Angular2 - here are step by step instructions on how to get
>   ZoomCharts running within the angular-seed application. Note that they
>   only describe the steps to get a sample running within the seed
>   application, not the steps required to build fully functional
>   component.
>
> 1. Copy `zoomcharts.d.ts` file into `/tools/manual_typings/project/`
>   folder.
>
> 2. Modify the `zoomcharts.d.ts` file to support CommonJS/SystemJS
>   module system by adding at the top of it these lines:
>
> `declare module "ZoomCharts" {
>       export = ZoomCharts; }`
>
> 3. In the `tools\project.config.ts` file add this line into the
>   constructor (of course, using CDN is optional) to register the library
>   with SystemJS loader:
>
> `this.addPackagesBundles([{    name: "ZoomCharts",    path:
>   "https://cdn.zoomcharts-cloud.com/1/latest/zoomcharts.js"  }]);`
>
> 4. Create a new component for the chart, for example,
>   `/src/client/app/home/zc-pie-chart.component.ts`
>
> ``` ///
>
> import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef }
>   from '@angular/core'; import { PieChart } from "ZoomCharts";
>
> @Component({
>       moduleId: module.id,
>       selector: "zc-pie-chart",
>       template: "PieChart is being initialized..." }) export class ZcPieChart implements AfterViewInit {
>
> ````
> @ViewChild("container") 
> private container: ElementRef;
>
> ngAfterViewInit() {
>     var x = new PieChart({
>         container: this.container.nativeElement,
>         assetsUrlBase: System.paths["ZoomCharts"] + "/../assets/",
>         data: [{
>             url: "https://zoomcharts.com/dvsl/data/pie-chart/browsers.json",
>         }]
>     });
> } } ```
> ````
>
> 5. Register the component in the module (in this sample case,
>   `home.module.ts`):
>
> ``` import { ZcPieChart } from './zc-pie-chart.component';
>
> ..   declarations: [..other components.., ZcPieChart], .. ```
>
> 6. Add it to the view, for example, `home.component.html`:
>
> `<zc-pie-chart></zc-pie-chart>`

## 2. [Integration with Webpack](https://forum.zoomcharts.com/t/integration-into-a-webpack-build-with-angular2/1043/2?u=karlis)

> Note: I tested this with Webpack 2.2.1.
>
> With Webpack you can use simple `import ZoomCharts from
>   './zoomcharts/zoomcharts.js';` and it works fine - including bundling
>   of the `zoomcharts.js` code.
>
> Though in such case ZoomCharts will now load dependencies such as
>   `moment.js` by itself even if they are already included in the webpack
>   bundle. To enable loading `moment.js` from the bundle, I used this
>   `webpack.config.js` file (and using the
>   [`imports-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader)
>   plugin):
>
> ```js var path = require('path');
>
> module.exports = {
>       entry: './index.js',
>       output: {
>           filename: 'bundle.js',
>           path: path.resolve(__dirname)
>       },
>       resolve: {
>           alias: {
>               "moment": path.resolve(__dirname, "zoomcharts", "assets", "moment.js"),
>               "moment-timezone": path.resolve(__dirname, "zoomcharts", "assets", "moment-tz.js"),
>               "zoomcharts": path.resolve(__dirname, "zoomcharts", "zoomcharts.js"),
>           }
>       },
>       module: {
>           rules: [
>               {
>                   test: path.resolve(__dirname, "zoomcharts", "zoomcharts.js"),
>                   loader: {
>                       loader: "imports-loader",
>                       options: {
>                           "moment": "moment",
>                           "momentTimezone": "moment-timezone",
>                           // workaround that sets window.moment as required by zoomcharts.js
>                           "_": ">window.moment=moment;"
>                       }
>                   }
>               }
>           ],
>       } }; ```

Answer (score 0):

first install zoomchart dependency

**npm  install --save @dvsl/zoomcharts**

Html

```html
<script src="https://cdn.zoomcharts-cloud.com/1/latest/zoomcharts.js"></script>
<div id='demo' style='width:100%; height:300px;'></div>
```

in ts file create a method

```
import * as zc from '@dvsl/zoomcharts';
import { WindowRef } from './../../WindowRef';
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

export class ZoomChartImplementation implements OnInit{

private zc: any = zc;

constructor(private winRef: WindowRef){
winRef.nativeWindow.ZoomChartsLicense = 'INSERT YOUR ZOOM CHART LICENSE HERE';
winRef.nativeWindow.ZoomChartsLicenseKey ='INSERT YOUR ZOOM CHART LICENSE KEY HERE';
}

loadZoomChart(){
const PieChart = this.zc.PieChart;
const t = new PieChart({
  container: document.getElementById('demo'),
  area: { height: 350 },
  data: {
    preloaded: {
      subvalues: [
        {
          id: 'foo', value: 100, subvalues: [
            { id: 'foo-1', value: 50, style: { expandable: false } },
            { id: 'foo-2', value: 50, style: { expandable: false } }
          ]
        },
        { id: 'bar', value: 50, style: { expandable: false } },
        { id: 'baz', value: 30, style: { expandable: false } }
      ]
    }
  }
});

}

}
```

you can use any chart instead of pie-chart in my example
**this.zc.ANY_CHART**